# Prevent Tkinter Text widget from resizing on font change

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I tried results from other answers but that didn't solve my Problem.

Here is a screenshot of my App on which I am working:
[image: My Application]

There above, (the one with >myIDLE text) is my Text box in disabled state.

When I decrease the font and use `sticky="nsew"` method, it works fine. But, when I increase the font and use the same method, something like this happens:

[image: On Increasing Font Size]

How to permanently FIX the size?
Currently I am declaring size like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.title("myIDLE Window")
root.iconbitmap(".\\resources\\images\\myIDLE.ico")
root.resizable(0, 0)

swidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
sheight = root.winfo_screenheight()

mainf = Frame(root)
mainf.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=7)
display = Text(mainf, height=int(33*(sheight/864)), width=int(112*(swidth/1536)))
display.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

I read in one answer about a similar question to use `.grid_propogate(False)`

I used it with following result:

1. On root window: Nothing changed
2. On Frame (`mainf`): Screen became white[image: White Screen]
3. On Text Widget: Nothing Changed

Please tell a way so I fix this problem
Also I am sorry I cant share my full code, but pls feel free to ask any part of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the text widget to be a specific size in pixels, the following technique works:

1. Create a frame with the size that you want
2. turn geometry propagation off for this frame
3. create a text widget with a width of 1 and a height of 1, using the frame as its master
4. add the text widget to the frame so that it fills the frame.
5. add the frame to your app however you want, using `grid`, `pack`, or `place`.

The following example will appear to create a text widget that is 400 pixels wide and tall. Changing the font will not change the size since it is the frame controlling the size of the text widget rather than the text widget controlling the size of the frame.

```
import tkinter as tk
...
text_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=400, height=400)
text_frame.pack_propagate(0)
text = tk.Text(text_frame, width=1, height=1)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
...
```

Comment: Works Flawlessly! This is exactly what I wanted. Thank You :D

Answer (score 1):

Found this question through Google. Ended up finding an easy solution.

By using the `root.geometry()` method, increasing and decreasing font will no longer change the size of the window.

For example, you may do `root.geometry("250x250")`.

I imagine some background Boolean gets ticked off upon its usage that says "the program specified a size for the window, so it probably doesn't want to be changed through external means."